# Unable to install Kile(LATEX) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, latex

I am trying to install kile using this command

```
sudo apt-get install kile
```

it is showing error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kile : Depends: kde-runtime (> 4:4.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried this command to add PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kile/stable
```

it is showing error

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"
```

To remove this problem, I executed

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

then it is again showing error message

```
Package software-properties-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-properties-common' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I installed from the live preview ppa:kile/livepreview , the steps should be the same though.

- add repository.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kile/livepreview
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- install okular first.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install okular
  ```
- then install kile.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install kile
  ```
- if it still gives errors regarding missing dependencies and broken
  packages, use fix command in apt-get.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```